# what is += (o, arg) => actually achieving?

Tags: c#

Sorry to ask all, but I'm an old hand Vb.net guy who's transferring to c#.  I have  the following piece of code that seems to activate when the (in this case) postAsync method is fired.  I just don;t understand what the code is doing (as follows):-

```
app.PostCompleted +=
    (o, args) =>
    {
        if (args.Error == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Picture posted to wall successfully.");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show(args.Error.Message);
        }
    };
```

if anyone could explain what the += (o,args) => is actually acheiving I'd be so greatful....

many thanks in advance.
Tim

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`(o,args) =>` defines a lambda expression that takes two parameters named `o` and `args`. The types of those parameters is inferred according to the type of `PostCompleted` (if `PostCompleted` is an `EventHandler`, then they will be respectively of type `Object` and `EventArgs`). The expression's body then follows after the `=>`.

The result is than added as an handler to `PostCompleted`.

As such, it's a less verbose way to write:

```
app.PostCompleted += delegate(object o, EventArgs args)
{
    // ...
};
```

Which is a shorthand for:

```
void YourHandler(object o, EventArgs args)
{
    // ...
}

// ...

app.PostCompleted += YourHandler;
```

Comment: Which is, itself, shorthand for `app.PostCompleted += new EventHandler(YourHandler);`.

Comment: You don't even need to have "new EventHandler". C# compiler is smart enough to infer which delegate to use.  So a shorter shortcut is `app.PostCompleted += YourHandler;`

Comment: @Sung I think that's exactly what he said.

Answer (score 8):

That is an added handler for the PostCompleted event using a lambda expression. It is similar to

```
  app.PostCompleted += MyHandler;

  // ...

  private void MyHandler(object sender, EventArgs e) {
      // ...
  }
```

But when using lambda expressions, you can't detach the handler easily.

Answer (score 5):

It's shorthand for a delegate defining the event handler for the POST completion event:

```
app.PostCompleted += delegate(object o, EventArgs args) { 
    // ...
};
```

See also [Anonymous Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yw3tz5k%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

Assuming `PostCompleted` is an event, you are basically creating an event handler using lambda notation.

This code snipped is equivalent to:

```
app.PostCompleted += delegate (o, args)
{
    if (args.Error == null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Picture posted to wall successfully.");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show(args.Error.Message);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

The vb.net equivalent would look like this:

```
AddHandler app.PostCompleted, Function(o, args)
        ''# ...
    End Function
```

Note that this requires Visual Studio 2010/.Net 4, but the C# code works back in Visual Studio 2008/.Net 3.5.

But that's only partly true.  In C#, this is a way to define a method as an event handler in one place.  In VB.Net, you can use the `Handles` keyword, and so the actual equivalent might look more like this:

```
Public Sub App_PostCompleted(ByVal Sender as Object, ByVall e As EventArgs) Handles app.PostCompleted
    ''#
End Sub
```

But even that's not completely equivalent, since you gave the method a name and can call it from anywhere.  The only reference to the C# code (and thus the only way to call it) is through the event subscription.

Answer (score 2):

The `(o,args) =>` part is a [lambda expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx), which is an anonymous function.

the `+=` part assigns the lambda expression to be called when the event fires.